# Do I need to recreate a dataset for every pipeline run?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm currently following through the tutorial "https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/build-pipeline" to remind myself about Vertex pipeline format, and it uses the component:

ImageDatasetCreateOp

Every time I run the pipeline, it recreates the dataset, which takes a long time (10+ minutes). What is the recommended way to work with dataset objects? Is it really to recreate them every single pipeline run?

It's odd because I used to work with Vertex a year ago, and don't remember ever doing that, but I can't for the life of me find any reference to "create if not exists", or even how other people get around this online.

(what I tried: running the pipeline, it recreates the dataset every time, which is very time consuming)

Comment: (Just a note, I realise I can use python to make a conditional, while constructing the pipeline, it's more whether or not this is what is actually preferred for dataset use I was wondering about. What is best practice, recreating everytime or reusing?)

Comment: As per my understanding, you can reuse the dataset, You need to recreate the dataset when you witness performance degradation or when new data is created. Also for better understanding on how to manage pipeline and its codes, you can refer to this [link1](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/best-practices-managing-vertex-pipelines-code),[link2](https://towardsdatascience.com/adapting-to-changes-of-data-by-building-mlops-pipeline-in-vertex-ai-3f8ebd19a869).